# Getting API's using Python

Tags: python

I've been trying to grab a price from BTC-E price API,I can't just specify `price[109:116]` for example. because it will just print 2 numbers in the wrong format if such happened. I just need to grab whats after "last:"

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError

def btceapi():
    request = Request('https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker')
    try:
        response = urlopen(request)
        price = response.read()
        print price[109:116]
    except URLError, e:
        print 'Not Found'

btceapi()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `price` variable you retrieved from the API is

> {"ticker":{"high":298.99899,"low":263.20001,"avg":281.0995,"vol":10566249.17861,"vol_cur":37737.87504,"last":291,"buy":291.493,"sell":291.001,"updated":1436554875,"server_time":1436554876}}'

That's [JSON](http://json.org/), which you can parse into a dictionary with:

```
import json

<snip...>
    price = response.read()
    print json.loads(price)["ticker"]["last"]
```